# where to put Drive API Client Library for Java to use in my android project

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I encounter error on compilation android application like this

[image]

so I found that I need to download 
 [Drive API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2)

what I wondering is what file I want to include in my project and where to  put it in.

Comment: Your application is gradle based or Eclipse based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the maven central repository to your build.gradle, so it automatically gets downloaded from there on build.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
    ....
}
```

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2#add-library-to-your-project